# Pentaho Data Integration - Star schema (PostgreSQL)

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a CSV file with data and the database I need for the star schema.
However, the CSV file doesn't have the ID's of the dimensions tables (the primary keys), which means I only get those ID's after inserting the data into the dimension's tables (the ID will be an auto-increment value).

This means that first I need to load the data into the dimensions and after that, I need to read the dimensions tables (to know the ID's) and the remaning data from the CSV file and load all that into the facts table.

To load the data into the dimensions,I made [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYNwp.png) Transformation and it works perfectly.

The problem is in getting the ID's from the tables (and, simultaneously, the remaning data from the CSV file) and load all that into the facts table.

I don't know if it is even possible to do all this in a single Transformation.

Any suggestions ?

I would really appreciate any help you could provide. (A sketch of the correct Transformation would be great)

Answer (score 0):

This entire thing is possible in one job not in one transformation.
Create a job,inside that select two transformation.
First load the dimension table using first transformation and in next transformation load the fact table.